# Как прокручивать ScrollView в режиме Design при построении приложения?

Tags: android, android-studio, прокрутка, android-scrollview, scrollview

Мне нужно добавить большое кол-во `ImageButton` на страницу. Я добавил `ScrollView` в xml для того, что бы можно было листать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда запускаю приложение, то вижу его и могу прокручивать, но когда нахожусь в режиме разработки, то очень тяжело добавлять новые кнопки т.к. тут уже не могу прокрутить страничку.
Есть, конечно, вариант добавлять их через `TextView` в xml, но это совсем не удобно.

Возможно что то подскажите?

Comment: Раз у вас так много кнопок, то мне кажется тут RelativeLayout не очень подходит. Попробуйте что-нибудь типа GridView. Он уже со скроллингом

Comment: "бросайте" их не на макет экрана, а на контейнер `RelativeLayout` в окне *Component Tree* слева (на вашем скриншоте). Там же можно двигать их относительно друг-друга. Так же для такой верстки уместнее корневой контейнер `TableLayout` или `GridLayout`, но никак не `RelativeLayout`

Answer (score 1):

Неизвестно сколько вам необходимо добавить кнопок imageButton. Если относительно немного, то можно прямо в коде, но если их все же относительно много или же в дальнейшем возможно их увеличение, то посмотрите в сторону реализации RecyclerView при этом можно компоновку выполнить при помощи LayoutManager GridLayoutManager (располагает элементы в сетке) или LinearLayoutManager (показывает элементы  в вертикальном или горизонтальном скролящимся списке). Сами же imageButton можно реализовать в виде CardView.